# Cygwin installation: Missing /usr/bin and /usr/local/sbin directories

Tags: windows, unix, cygwin

I have Windows 7 64-bit PC. I just installed Cygwin latest version 2.6.0 on it in `c:\cygwin64` directory. During installation I make sure that I selected these packages: `gcc-core`, `make`, `openssl`, `ssh`, `vim`, `emacs`, `scp` and `ftp`. The installation completed successfully.

Now I am looking at the `c:\cygwin64` directory and I see some directories are missing:

- `/bin` (directory exist)
- `/sbin` (directory exist)
- `/usr/bin` (directory does not exist)
- `/usr/sbin` (directory exist)
- `/usr/local/bin` (directory exist)
- `/usr/local/sbin` (directory does not exist)

So why `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/sbin` directories are missing? Are they obsolete?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking from within the cygwin bash?
`/usr/bin` is really `c:\cygwin\bin`

Comment: I was looking from Windows explorer. I was expecting that there would be a `c:\cygwin64\usr\bin` directory but it was not there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Erik said, `c:\cygwin64\usr\bin` is really `c:\cygwin64\bin` in your case.  As for `/usr/local/sbin/`, perhaps nothing was going to be installed there from those packages, so it was not created.

According to the [FAQ for the Cygwing directory structure](https://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.using.directory-structure)

> 4.33. Why the weird directory structure?   Why do /lib and /usr/lib (and /bin, /usr/bin) point to the same thing?
>
> Why use mounts instead of symbolic links?
>
> Can I use a disk root (e.g., C:) as Cygwin root? Why is this
>   discouraged?
>
> After a new installation in the default location, your mount points
>   will look something like this:
>
> ```
>  bash$ mount  
>  C:\cygwin\bin on /usr/bin type ntfs (binary,auto)  
>  C:\cygwin\lib on /usr/lib type ntfs (binary,auto)  
>  C:\cygwin on / type ntfs (binary,auto)  
>  C: on /cygdrive/c type ntfs (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
> ```
>
> Note that /bin and /usr/bin point to the same location, as do /lib and
>   /usr/lib. This is intentional, and you should not undo these mounts
>   unless you really know what you are doing.
>
> Various applications and packages may expect to be installed in /lib
>   or /usr/lib (similarly /bin or /usr/bin). Rather than distinguish
>   between them and try to keep track of them (possibly requiring the
>   occasional duplication or symbolic link), it was decided to maintain
>   only one actual directory, with equivalent ways to access it.
>
> Symbolic links had been considered for this purpose, but were
>   dismissed because they do not always work on Samba drives. Also,
>   mounts are faster to process because no disk access is required to
>   resolve them.
>
> Note that non-cygwin applications will not observe Cygwin mounts (or
>   symlinks for that matter). For example, if you use WinZip to unpack
>   the tar distribution of a Cygwin package, it may not get installed to
>   the correct Cygwin path. So don't do this!
>
> It is strongly recommended not to make the Cygwin root directory the
>   same as your drive's root directory, unless you know what you are
>   doing and are prepared to deal with the consequences. It is generally
>   easier to maintain the Cygwin hierarchy if it is isolated from, say,
>   C:. For one thing, you avoid possible collisions with other
>   (non-cygwin) applications that may create (for example) \bin and \lib
>   directories. (Maybe you have nothing like that installed now, but who
>   knows about things you might add in the future?)

Comment: Why/how is it that `C:\cygwin64\bin` equates to usr/bin in Linux? Since when was the Cygwin root folder also its usr folder? That's quite confusing, with there also being a `usr` folder in the root.

Comment: @Hashim.  Updated the answer to include the FAQ.

Comment: My confusion lies in the fact that there is no /usr/bin or usr/lib on my Cygwin installation. I have C:\cygwin\bin, C:\cygwin\lib, and then usr/local/bin and usr/local/lib.

Comment: @Hashim, from within the Cygwin terminal, what is the output from `ls -l /usr/bin` and `ls -l /usr/lib`?

Comment: Do you want me to copy-paste the entire output of both, or did you want to know something specific?

Comment: ?  Neither, I wanted you to realize that C:\cygwin\bin is mounted as /usr/bin, etc., so you do in fact have those directories.